# fix message in channel telegram bot api

Tags: telegram-bot

I read all the telegram documentation and didn't find any subject related to  fix message on the channel.

Has anyone done something like that?

Ref.: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

Thanks

Comment: Fix message? Do you mean _pin message_? See [pinChatMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#pinchatmessage) then.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you guys! It worked for me:  pinChatMessage 

Thanks @Xeelley